# How are the two lambs offered on the Sabbath in Numbers 28:9?

Tags: law, numbers, sacrifice

Numbers 28:9 NASB

> 9 ‘Then on the sabbath day ***two male lambs*** one year old without defect, and two-tenths of an [d]ephah of fine flour mixed with oil as a grain offering, and its drink offering:

These two lambs offered on the Sabbath are additional to the daily sacrifices of one lamb in the morning & one at twilight. ([Numbers 28:10](http://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=Numbers_28:10&version=NASB&interface=print) NASB).

My question is how & when are they offered?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The next verse makes it clear that we are dealing with a burnt offering.

> On the sabbath day: two male lambs a year old without blemish, and two-tenths of an ephah of choice flour for a grain offering, mixed with oil, and its drink offering— this is the **burnt offering** for every sabbath, in addition to the regular burnt offering and its drink offering. (28:9-10 NRSV)

Accordingly, the law of Leviticus 1:10-13 applies:

> If your gift for a **burnt offering** is from the flock, from the **sheep** or goats, your offering shall be a male without blemish. It shall be slaughtered on the north side of the altar before the Lord, and Aaron’s sons the priests shall dash its blood against all sides of the altar. It shall be cut up into its parts, with its head and its suet, and the priest shall arrange them on the wood that is on the fire on the altar; but the entrails and the legs shall be washed with water. Then the priest shall offer the whole and turn it into smoke on the altar; it is a burnt offering, an offering by fire of pleasing odor to the Lord.

As to when it was offered, rabbinic tradition puts it after the morning continual offering and before the evening continual offering (Mishnah Zevachim 10:1; BT Pesachim 58b). Otherwise, the text itself offers no time other than saying that it was offered on the sabbath.

Comment: The hebrew source dosen't say that the lambs are addition to the two on weekdays. It speaks on the oil and flour that pour on the lambs on shabbath.

Comment: @A.Meshu The words "in addition to the regular burnt offering" show that it was another offering separate from the regular burnt offering

Comment: Have you read the source? It's intresting to say something based on translation (over translation)..

Comment: @A.Meshu The word על can mean in addition to. See for example Numbers 2:20. Both are referred to as a burnt offering. A burnt offering (עולה) is clearly not the flour and oil which is referred to as a מנחה. Your interpretation is interesting, but I don't think it's correct in light of the wording of the verse. If you somehow found a historical reference to the sacrifices being as you mentioned, it would be much more convincing

Comment: You can detach one word from a phrase and translate it, but מנחה here is part from expression: סֹלֶת מִנְחָה בְּלוּלָה בַשֶּׁמֶן--וְנִסְכּוֹ. Wath the root נ.ס.כ here - it is ceremonial act when doing important things like declare new king, burn animals on special days, etc.

Comment: @A.Meshu I see what you're saying. But maybe you could support your actual answer with a better explanation. As it is, your answer is just making an assertion, even though you seem to have thought about it more than your answer reveals

Answer (score 0):

"These two lambs offered on the Sabbath are additional to the daily sacrifices of one lamb in the morning & one at twilight."

Not.

On 9 it says that in addition to those two lambs everyday, the priest need to pour plate contains oil and  finely sifted flour on them (on each lamb, morning and evening).

So it the same two lams - just with the additionals - cause it shabbath.

Comment: The text says that the Sabbath offering is *in addition* to the regular burnt offering.

Comment: @ba Where does it say that these are additional?

Comment: @Ruminator 28:10

Comment: @AMeshu, it appears  David Guzik argrees:  "a. And on the Sabbath day two lambs: Every Sabbath day, an additional lamb was sacrificed every morning and every evening." Do you have any evidence that these were not additional? Thanks.

Comment: Rashi has this:  "in addition to the continual burnt offering: This refers to the additional [musaf] offerings, besides those two lambs of the continual burnt offering. And it teaches us that they [the additional sacrifices] may be offered only between the two continual offerings. Similarly, in the case of all the additional offerings it says, “In addition to the continual burnt offering” for this teaching. — [Sifrei Pinchas 40]"  https://www.chabad.org/library/bible_cdo/aid/9956#lt=primary&showrashi=true

Comment: I'm sorry but verse 10 dosen't say that this two lambs are additional but rather speaks on the oil plates as the addition. And as for Rashi - it is known that he used to add details that dosen't mention in the scripts. The most known time is when Jossef put on bore and the bible says that it was empty but Rashi decide that it wasn't empty but full with snakes and scorpions. Rashi system of hermeneutics based on legends most of the time and not on text itself.